# How to clear the value of an input if I write something on other input using css?

Tags: css

Suppose I have an input person name and another input business name:

```html
<input name="nameofperson" id="nameofperson" class="form-control">
<input name="nameofbusiness" id="nameofbusiness" class="form-control" value="1234567">
```

If I started writing something on the nameofperson input. I want to clear the value of nameofbusiness, how to do that using CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What you want to do is not possible through the Css,but you can do that using javascript or jquery.

*With Javascript :*

```js
var nameofperson  = document.getElementById('nameofperson');
var nameofbusiness = document.getElementById('nameofbusiness');
nameofperson.oninput = function() {
  nameofbusiness.value = '';
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="nameofperson" id="nameofperson"  class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="nameofbusiness" id="nameofbusiness" class="form-control" value="1234567">
```

*With Jquery :*

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#nameofperson').keyup(function(){
    $('#nameofbusiness').val('');
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="nameofperson" id="nameofperson"  class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="nameofbusiness" id="nameofbusiness" class="form-control" value="1234567">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't clear an input field's value using CSS. However, you can use JavaScript/JQuery for that.
Please find the working example.

```js
$("#person").on("keyup", function(){
$("#business").val("");
});
```

```css
input {
width: 350px;
height: 30px;
text-indent: 5;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="person" placeholder="Enter name of person">
<input type="text" id="business" placeholder="Enter your Business">
```

Answer (score 1):

You add same class name for both input. For exampale I add 'nameofSomething' class.

and the jquery

```
$(".nameofSomething").keypress(function () {      
    var id = $(this).attr('id')
    var text = $("#" + id).val();
    $(".nameofSomething").val('');
    $("#" + id).val(text);
});
```

You can change keypress to change, blur...or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically done by javascript and not by css.
CSS as the name says is for styling purpose.
you can do this by javascript easily using onfocus method:

```
<input type="text" onfocus="document.getElementById('nameofbusiness').value = ''">
```